# How to uninstall lightdm?

Tags: 12.04, unity, lightdm

I removed Unity from my computer. But still **lightdm** is showing when I typed `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. I want to remove it. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove an application in Ubuntu you can type in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

or remove it with all its configuration files:

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
```

Comment: I tried the seccond one and  Showing this **dpkg: warning: while removing lightdm, directory '/etc/lightdm' not empty so not removed**

Comment: There are another packages using this folder. try with `sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter` first.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

instead leaving out the purge, if anything does go wrong and you cannot log into a graphical session you can always drop to a terminal and restore LightDM.

After the remove if everything works properly you can then purge the config files ..

If you will do -

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
```

or

```
sudo aptitude purge lightdm
```

then you cant restore it back without installing.

Comment: And if something goes wrong? How do you restore it?

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```

I think that should work, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
sudo apt-get remove lightdm
```