# Stuck at loading screen after removing LightDM

Tags: 14.04, boot, unity, lightdm, cinnamon

I removed unity and installed cinnamon on my Ubuntu 14.04  LTS, everything was working fine. I recently removed LightDM in favour to the lock screen of cinnamon using this method [How to uninstall lightdm?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386899/how-to-uninstall-lightdm)
And now, it's stuck at loading screen (splash screen) showing Ubuntu logo and the animation so I can't access my desktop, terminal and text editor. PLEASE HELP! Thank you.

Comment: what happense when you run   ctrl + alt + f1 ?

Answer (score 1):

1- Run ctrl + alt + f2

2- Login with root or an admin.

3- `sudo apt-get install lightdm`

4- `sudo apt-get update` 

5- `sudo service lightdm start`

6- `sudo reboot`